# PHP convert date to string

Tags: php, string

I have a date object that I would like to convert to String. I tried looking it up but haven't came up with a good answer. The date is retrieved from a db and it looks like this:

```
object(DateTime)#1433 (3) {
    ["date"]=> string(19) "2014-06-04 00:00:00"
    ["timezone_type"]=> int(3)
    ["timezone"]=> string(19) "America/Los_Angeles"
}
```

I need it to just be "2014-06-04" to set as a parameter in another function. How do I convert it to just a string?

Comment: You should learn to use PHP's [online documentation](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).  It's quite helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the format function:

```
$dateString = $yourDateObject->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 2):

You already have a [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object, so you can use the [`format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method to format the date:

```
$date->format('Y-m-d');
```

You can find the list of format characters (like `Y`, `m`, or `d`) in the manual of [`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).